# Users cannot access File Manager

Tags: members, file-uploads, error, file-manager

I have a site running v 2.5.3 which all of a sudden has come up with a ton of errors and is not allowing the users to manage files. The errors look like this.

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: 1
Filename: cp/content_files.php
Line Number: 369
```

There's probably 30 errors in that file. Which then ends with

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Applications/AMPPS/www/ruffinos_lafayette/system/codeigniter/system/core/Exceptions.php:170)
Filename: core/Common.php
Line Number: 412
```

Super Admins have the ability to access this just fine, it's just users. I've deleted members, created new member groups, etc. Nothing has worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that the member had the ability to change file upload preferences on their own. They used that power to remove their own access and so the system was confused.